# Wrapping text with =HYPERLINK and XlsxWriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am using Excel's =HYPERLINK function to write hyperlinks in XlsxWriter. I am not using `write_url()` because my tab names begin with numbers and I also need to show a "friendly" name instead of the hyperlink. (Showing a friendly name does not seem to work with `write_url()`'s `'internal:...'` keyword.) The hyperlinking is working just fine but for some reason Excel is not wrapping the hyperlink even though I have set `'text_wrap'` to `True`. As you can see in the top picture Excel shows that Wrap Text is set (it is grayed out) but the text is not wrapped. If I click Wrap Text to deselect it, and then click it again to re-select it, it does wrap the text, as seen in the bottom picture.

I am using xlsxwriter 1.0.2 and Excel 2016.

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Wrap.xlsx')

ws = wb.add_worksheet('Test1')

wrap = wb.add_format({'text_wrap': True})

ws.write('A1', '=HYPERLINK("#Sheet1!A1", "A really long name here that does not wrap")', wrap)
ws.write('B1', 'Bye')

wb.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
wb.close()
```

[image: Link not wrapped]

[image: Link wrapped]

Comment: You're missing the call to save, but I see your point.

Comment: @MadPhysicist wb.close() writes and closes the file, no need to call a save function. [Close Docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#close)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I was thinking in openpyxl terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Showing a friendly name does not seem to work with write_url()'s 'internal:...' keyword.

It does:

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Wrap.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet('Test1')

wrap = wb.add_format({'text_wrap': True})

ws.write_url('A1', 'internal:Sheet1!A1', wrap,
             "A really long name here that does not wrap")
ws.write('B1', 'Bye')

wb.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
wb.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ah! I didn't put the format and the name parameters in the correct order when I was testing this. After fixing that and adding single quotes around sheet names whose first character is a number `write_url()` fixes my problem. I'll let someone else worry about why my original example didn't work. Thanks John for the answer and the great library. 189 sheets and 13,790 cells, hyperlinks all over, all done in a second!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `worksheet.write_url()` method and then use `worksheet.write()` to add formatting and text while preserving the hyperlink.

The code below produces the wrapped text.

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Wrap.xlsx')

ws = wb.add_worksheet('Test1')

wrap = wb.add_format({'text_wrap': True})

ws.write_url('A1',  'internal:Sheet1!A1')
ws.write('A1',  "A really long name here that does not wrap", wrap)
ws.write('B1', 'Bye')

wb.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
wb.close()
```

Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]